# Here-API : How to create own Layer with custom places

Tags: here-api

I would like to get more info on how to create his own layer with custom places for using it on a corridor request like in this example : http://developer.here.com/api-explorer#cls/route-search

In all these Here examples, the layerId = 30 is used. Is there any example how to upload cml or json data to create its own layer ? Thanks for your help.

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

Importing data is covered in the **Custom Location Extension** [User Guide](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/custom-location/topics/management-import-xml-async.html). You will need to make a `post` request sending an attached file.

A minimal HTML web-page for data import can be found below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>HERE - [Custom Location Service] - XML File Upload Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>XML File Upload Example</h1>
        <form action="http://stg.api.customlocation.nokia.com/v1/file/import/async/xml" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <label>xmlfile</label>
            <input type="file" name="xmlfile"><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

The administration of a layer is described in the **Administrator's User Guide** available [here](http://developer.here.com/documentation/versions#custom-location).

Comment: Hi Jason, I've seen that part of the user guide with the sample xml file (http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/custom-location/topics/management-import-xml-async.html) but what I do not understand is how do you first create a layer in order to get a layerID. And then, what are username/passwd, is it your credential (email/passwd) to sign-in on the website or different credentials ?

Comment: The online HTML documentation only covers data upload and queries. I think you'll need to look at the [Admin Guide](http://developer.here.com/documentation/download/location_custom_nlp/1.6.5/Custom%20Location%20Extension%20v1.6.5%20User%20Guide.pdf) which is available as a PDF to configure usernames and passwords